# What is the correct way to construct a Django ModelForm in a create/edit view?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Consider a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField(unique=True, db_index=True, max_length...)
    name = models.CharField(...)
    ...
```

(Aside: The purpose of the token is to be an alternative to displaying and using the ID in URLs; it is not the primary key.)

And its form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...    
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = '__all__' # Django 1.6
```

And its template:

```
...
<form action={% url 'create_or_edit_mymodel' %} ...>{% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.token.as_hidden }}

    <label for="id_name">Name:</label>
    {{ form.name }}
    ...
```

And, finally, its view:

```
def create_or_edit_mymodel(request, token=None):

    # [A] Entering via a hyperlink with the token, editing existing model
    if token: 
        m = models.MyModel.objects.filter(token=token).first()
        form = forms.MyForm(instance=m)

    # [B] Postback from form
    elif request.POST: 
        form = forms.MyForm(request.POST)

    # [C] Entering via a hyperlink without the token, creating new model
    else:
        m = create_new_mymodel(...) # somewhere else
        form = forms.MyForm(instance=m)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        saved = form.save()
        # Determine if 'Save' or 'Save & Close' was clicked... assume 'Save'...
        form = forms.MyForm(instance=saved)

    return shortcuts.render(request, '...', { 'form': form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This doesn't work. The problem is that the model's ID doesn't seem to be available to Django, so entering the view at [A] populates the form with everything as expected, but clicking 'Save' and entering the view at [B] attempts to save a model with no ID, and the unique constraint on the 'token' field fires.

I tried adding the id field to the form:

```
{{ form.id.as_hidden }} # or...
{{ form.pk.as_hidden }}
```

But nothing gets rendered.

That view looks pretty uncomfortable to me, so I'm hoping I'm making this harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you should pass both `request.POST` **and instance** to form init:

```
# [B] Postback from form
elif request.POST: 
    form = forms.MyForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
```

Comment: Where is the instance coming from? Do I look it up again using the hidden token field the way I do in [A]?

Comment: @Seth from view argument (token). Your form `action` should point to same location with same token

Comment: It's not available there any more on a postback, but I can pull it from the request.POST. I'm going to edit your answer; hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Seth you edit rejected by someone. Anyway, check what you actually have in form action - token should be in your browser location in edit url and ofcourse after you posted form in that location. And ofcourse you can go your way and get it from POST